# Error "const Discord = require(discord.js) ^ ReferenceError: discord is not defined"

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, discord, discord.js

Hi there so i have a weird error that i get that says this
"const Discord = require(discord.js)
^
ReferenceError: discord is not defined"
here is the code i have written is there a error that i put in there?

```js
const Discord = require(discord.js)
const Client = new Discord.Client
const prefix = "/";
Client.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log('Bot is online.');
})
Client.on('message', (Message)=>{
    if(!Message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(Message.content.startsWith(prefix + "hello")){
        Message.channel.send("Hello.")
    }
})
Client.login("<Token Here>");
```

Comment: Hey welcome to the community, you need to wrap the module name in quotations: 'discord.js' and there should be brackets after Client when you initiate it:Discord.Client()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the " or ' in:

```
const Discord = require(discord.js)
```

so try :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining something in const syntax, you must always use " or '.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing/requiring anything you have to pass it as a string. You essentially tried to pass it as a variable.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap module name using quotations `"` or `'` .

Use the command below :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

Answer (score -1):

That's right:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client
const prefix = "/";
Client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online.')
});

Client.on('message', (Message) => {
    if(!Message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(Message.content.startsWith(prefix + "hello")){
        Message.channel.send("Hello.")
    }
});

Client.login("<Token Here>");
```